# jgesture is not working in phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have included jgesture.min.js   but swipe functon is not working can aybody tell how to solve problem

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery.mobile/jgestures.min.js"></script>



this.container.bind("swiperight", function(event, body) {
      alert("you swiped!");
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem with the design of the plugin.

swiperight will only fire if the swipe has **zero** movement on the Y axis.

Please see: [Only swipeone is working with jGestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9413435/only-swipeone-is-working-with-jgestures)

Answer (score 2):

The trick is:

```
… .bind('swipeone swiperight', …
```

You have to bind it to both events. only swiperight won't work. took me 3 hrs to figure that out :D

Best,
 Rico

Comment: That's not true exactly. This event also fires if you swipe up or down. It binds two events, where actually only swipeone is fired.